# How to continuously bind to Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, charts, data-visualization

How do I bind to a `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` object, so that the chart gets updated when the underlying data changes?

I managed to bind a chart with an underlying array of doubles:

```
double[] DoubleArray = new double[] {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};

MyChart.Series[0].Points.DataBindY(DoubleArray);
```

But it won't update the chart when the values in the array are changed.

So I tried to realise the Binding with a BindingList:

```
class Model
{
    public BindingList<double> DoubleList { get; set; }
    public Model()
    {
        //Initialize BindingList
        DoubleList = new BindingList<double>();
        DoubleList.Add(1.0);
        DoubleList.Add(2.0);
        DoubleList.Add(3.0);
        DoubleList.Add(4.0);
    }

    public void UpdateModel(double y0, double y1, double y2, double y3)
    {
        //Just a simple example - of course you could do checks and only
        //update values where required.
        DoubleList[0] = y0;
        DoubleList[1] = y1;
        DoubleList[2] = y2;
        DoubleList[3] = y3;
    }
}
```

Code placed in form:

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    Model _Model = new Model();

    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyChart.Series[0].Points.DataBindY(_Model.DoubleList); //Binds successfully and displays chart with initial values.

    }

    //Why doesn't this update the chart?
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _Model.UpdateModel(4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0);  //Has no effect on chart... what do I do wrong?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    Model _Model = new Model();

    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyChart.Series.First().XValueMember = "X";
        MyChart.Series.First().YValueMembers = "Y";

        MyChart.DataSource = _Model.DoubleList;
    }

    private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        _Model.UpdateModel( 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 );
        MyChart.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works - I don't even need to set the XValueMember to "X" - setting the YValueMembers is sufficient for my needs. Can you shed some light on why I have to set the value to "Y"? The float doesn't really have a "Y" property...

Comment: I don't think you actually need those lines, because as you said float doesn't have a "Y" property. The `XValueMember` and `YValueMember` are used when binding to complex objects (like `DataTable`)

Comment: I understand your comment, but when testing the code it actually made a difference if I use the YValueMembers. When omitted, setting the DataSource and calling DataBind did not work. Am I the only one who thinks this to be strange?

Comment: Im taking this answer as correct because it is a working solution. It seems that the Chart Binding is only handled once when you do the actual call. You'll have to handle changes by repeatetely calling .DataBind again.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a call to `MyChart.DataBind()` (or `MyChart.Series[0].Points.DataBind()`) after updating your list. You could also create a new `BindingSource` from your `BindingList`, and bind to that instead of the list, which should take care of updates automatically:

```
BindingSource source = new BindingSource(_Model.DoubleList, null);
MyChart.Series[0].Points.DataBindY(source);

// In your button click method
_Model.Update(4, 5, 6, 7); // This should update your chart, since you used a BindingSource
```

Comment: I applied your logic, but in fact it doesn't work. Only if I call MyChart.Series[0].Points.DataBindY(source); on each button click it will work. The databinding seems to behave differently for charts than for other controls it seems.